# Jacobian: boundaries between regions of inverse transform

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**What does it mean by:**

**"the region for inverse transform on x-y plane are separated by the line on which the Jacobian vanishes?"**

In $R^2$ let a curvilinear coordinate system $(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})$ be defined from rectangular coordinates $(x,y)$ by the equation:

$$T : \begin{cases}
\tilde{x} = xy \\
\tilde{y} = y^2 
\end{cases}
$$

The jacobian is given by:

$$J = \begin{bmatrix}
y & x \\
0 & 2y 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Inverse Transform is give by two regions:

**for $y > 0$:**

$$T^{-1} = \begin{cases}
x=\frac{\tilde{x}}{\sqrt{\tilde{y}}} \\
y=\sqrt{\tilde{y}}
\end{cases}$$

**for $y < 0$:**

$$T^{-1} = \begin{cases}
x=-\frac{\tilde{x}}{\sqrt{\tilde{y}}} \\
y= -\sqrt{\tilde{y}}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: You need $\mathcal J(T)(x,y)\neq 0$ in order for $T^{-1}$ to be defined in a neighborhood of $(x,y).$

Answer (score 1):

It should be

> the regions for inverse transform on x-y plane are separated by the line on which the Jacobian **determinant** vanishes?

Note that the Jacobian matrix is invertible iff its determinant is not zero. Also, the inverse of Jacobian is the Jacobian of $T^{-1}$.

For your example, the Jacobian determinant is $2y^2$. It is zero at $y=0$. $T^{-1}$ is not defined at $y=0$. Also, the two solutions are separated by the line $y=0$.